# How do I create entry widgets based on a number chosen by the user

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote this code to allow users to choose the number of players in a tournament. The options are all powers of 2 so it can eventually end with a 1vs1. I want the next screen to allow users to input the names of each player. For this, I need the code to take the option selected by the user and create that many entry widgets in which the user can input the names of each player. For example, if the user selected the option "4", then the next screen would contain 4 entry widgets in which the user can input the names of each of the 4 players. How would I write this code?

```
from logging import root
from tkinter import *
import os
from turtle import bgcolor, screensize
import tkinter as tk

def enter_numberofitems1():
   enter_numberofitems1_screen = Tk()
   enter_numberofitems1_screen.geometry("1000x500")
   enter_numberofitems1_screen.title("Enter Number of Players/Teams")
   Label(enter_numberofitems1_screen, text= "Choose Number of Players/Teams", bg="yellow", 
   width="300", height="5", font=("Calibri", 20)).pack()
   Var = IntVar()
   Radiobutton(enter_numberofitems1_screen, text="4", variable=Var, value=4, height="2", 
   width= "10", fg="green", font=("Calibri", 10)).pack()
   Radiobutton(enter_numberofitems1_screen, text="8", variable=Var, value=8, height="2", 
   width= "10", fg="green", font=("Calibri", 10)).pack()
   Radiobutton(enter_numberofitems1_screen, text="16", variable=Var, value=16, height="2", 
   width= "10", fg="green", font=("Calibri", 10)).pack()
   Radiobutton(enter_numberofitems1_screen, text="32", variable=Var, value=32, height="2", 
   width= "10", fg="green", font=("Calibri", 10)).pack()
   Radiobutton(enter_numberofitems1_screen, text="64", variable=Var, value=64, height="2", 
   width= "10", fg="green", font=("Calibri", 10)).pack()
   Button(enter_numberofitems1_screen, text="Submit", height="5", width = "30", 
   bg="green").pack()
```

Comment: use `Button(..., command=function_name)` to run function when you click button. And this functions should get data and create new elements. But this may need to use `global Var` to keep value in global variable which you can access in other functions. BTW `command=` needs function's name without `()`

Comment: if you want to show in the same window then you could keep all elements in `Frame` and later you can simply use `frame.destroy()` to remove all elements and make place for new widgets (which you could also keep in new `Frame`). But if you want to open in second window then you have to remeber to use `Toplevel` instead of `Tk` to create second window.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of mistakes in your code above:

1- You imported a lot of libraries which have no use in your code

2- You put your code inside a function, when you run your code nothing will happen as you didn't call the function

You only need to import

```
from tkinter import *
```

And delete the function called enter_numberofitems1

Full Code:

```
from tkinter import *

def radio_input():
    teams_gui = Tk()
    teams_gui.title("Teams")
    teams_gui.geometry("500x750")
    no_teams = Var.get()
    if no_teams == 4:
      for i in range(4):
        entry = Entry(teams_gui)
        entry.pack()
    elif no_teams == 8:
      for i in range(8):
        entry = Entry(teams_gui)
        entry.pack()
    elif no_teams == 16:
      for i in range(16):
        entry = Entry(teams_gui)
        entry.pack()
    elif no_teams == 32:
      for i in range(32):
        entry = Entry(teams_gui)
        entry.pack()
    elif no_teams == 64:
      for i in range(64):
        entry = Entry(teams_gui)
        entry.pack()

enter_numberofitems1_screen = Tk()
enter_numberofitems1_screen.geometry("1000x500")
enter_numberofitems1_screen.title("Enter Number of Players/Teams")
Label(enter_numberofitems1_screen, text= "Choose Number of Players/Teams", bg="yellow", 
width="300", height="5", font=("Calibri", 20)).pack()
Var = IntVar()
Radiobutton(enter_numberofitems1_screen, text="4", variable=Var, value=4, height="2", 
width= "10", fg="green", font=("Calibri", 10)).pack()
Radiobutton(enter_numberofitems1_screen, text="8", variable=Var, value=8, height="2", 
width= "10", fg="green", font=("Calibri", 10)).pack()
Radiobutton(enter_numberofitems1_screen, text="16", variable=Var, value=16, height="2", 
width= "10", fg="green", font=("Calibri", 10)).pack()
Radiobutton(enter_numberofitems1_screen, text="32", variable=Var, value=32, height="2", 
width= "10", fg="green", font=("Calibri", 10)).pack()
Radiobutton(enter_numberofitems1_screen, text="64", variable=Var, value=64, height="2", 
width= "10", fg="green", font=("Calibri", 10)).pack()
Button(enter_numberofitems1_screen, text="Submit", height="5", width = "30", 
bg="green", command=radio_input).pack()

enter_numberofitems1_screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Button should have `command=function_name` to run function which will get value and create new widgets.

And you have to use `global` variable to keep value and get it in another
function. Without `global` it will keep it in local variable and you can't access it from other function

If you want to show new elements in the same window then you could keep widgets in `Frame` and later you can `destroy()` this frame to remove all widgets. OR use `.pack_forget()` to only hide frame - and later you can use again `.pack()` to show the same frame with previously selected value.

And if you want to show in second window (and keep previous one) then you should use `Toplevel` instead of `Tk` to create next windows.

---

Minimal working code.

I removed fonts and colors to make it more readable.

I used `for`-loop to create all radiobuttons.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions before main code

def get_names():
    global entries

    for e in entries:
        print('name:', e.get())

def get_value():
    global frame
    global entries
    
    print('selected:', var.get())

    if var.get() > 0:
        frame.destroy()
        
        frame = tk.Frame(enter_numberofitems1_screen)
        frame.pack()  # has to be in separated line to assing `Frame()` to `frame`, not `pack()` to `frame`
        
        tk.Label(frame, text=f'Selected: {var.get()}').pack()
        
        entries = []
        for x in range(var.get()):
            e = tk.Entry(frame)
            e.pack()
            entries.append(e)

        tk.Button(frame, text="Submit", command=get_names).pack()
        
def enter_numberofitems1():
    global var  # inform function that `var = ...` will have to assign to global variable `var` instead of local variable `var`
    global frame
    global enter_numberofitems1_screen

    enter_numberofitems1_screen = tk.Tk()

    enter_numberofitems1_screen.geometry("1000x500")
    enter_numberofitems1_screen.title("Enter Number of Players/Teams")
   
    frame = tk.Frame(enter_numberofitems1_screen)
    frame.pack()  # has to be in separated line to assing `Frame()` to `frame`, not `pack()` to `frame`
    
    tk.Label(frame, text="Choose Number of Players/Teams").pack()
    var = tk.IntVar(enter_numberofitems1_screen)

    for x in range(2, 7):
        value = 2**x
        tk.Radiobutton(frame, text=str(value), variable=var, value=value).pack()
    
    tk.Button(frame, text="Submit", command=get_value).pack()
    
    enter_numberofitems1_screen.mainloop()
    
# --- main ---

enter_numberofitems1()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)